# Missing deployment templates in Synapse 'main' branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse

Few days ago I had to recreate Azure Synapse Workspace. I had connected Git repository (Azure DevOps Git).
After Workspace recreation I reconnected to repo and restored whole project (pipelines, linked services etc.).

Unfortunately after this action template files are not being updated in main branch after Publishing changes in Synapse:

[image]

They are being updated only in Publish branch which should be rather read only:

[image]

I tried to create completely new repo, but with the same result - main folder is being created and synced properly:

[image]

but Templates folder and files are not created in main branch.

I'm using these templates for deployment to production and I need to make customizations so it's much easier to work with them in main branch.

Do you know how could I 'restore' previous behaviour?

Comment: I'm confused. You are making the changes workspace_publish branch which is read-only, but you are trying to push the changes to the main branch? Have you tried merging workspace_publish to your main branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Templates folder and files are not created in main branch.

To recover a deleted Azure Synapse instance that has source control configured either in GitGub or Azure DevOps, you need to create the new Branch. Follow below steps.

1. Create a new Azure Synapse instance of the service.
2. Reconfigure Git with the same settings, but make sure to import existing resources to the selected repository and choose `New branch`.

While configuring the repository, under `Collaboration branch` choose `+ Create new` and create a new branch.

[image]

3. Create a pull request to merge the changes to the collaboration branch and publish.
4. In case there was a Self-hosted Integration Runtime in a Synapse workspace, a new instance of the IR must be created in a workspace. For an on-premises or virtual machine IR instance, they must be uninstalled and reinstalled, and a new key obtained. After setup of the new Integration Runtime is completed, the Linked Service must be updated to point to new IR and the connection should be tested again, or it will fail with error invalid reference.

I have tried to repo the same with a sample pipeline in the workspace, and when I restored it I can see both pipeline and template folder in the Repo. Refer below image.

[image]

Please refer [Troubleshoot CI-CD, Azure DevOps, and GitHub issues in Azure Data Factory and Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ci-cd-github-troubleshoot-guide#cannot-recover-from-a-deleted-instance) to know more on backup and restore Azure Synapse.